# anacondaターミナルを開くとerror reportが表示される

Tags: python, macos, r, anaconda, zsh

anacondaターミナルを開くと以下のエラーレポートが表示されます。
errorの解消方法が分かる方教えてください。

```
/Users/username/.anaconda/navigator/a.tool ; exit;

# >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> ERROR REPORT <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/Users/username
/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/conda/cli/main.py", line 138, in main
        return activator_main()
      File "/Users/username/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/conda/activate.py", line 1098, in main
        print(activator.execute(), end='')
      File "/Users/username/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/conda/activate.py", line 182, in execute
        return getattr(self, self.command)()
      File "/Users/username/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/conda/activate.py", line 156, in activate
        builder_result = self.build_activate(self.env_name_or_prefix)
      File "/Users/username/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/conda/activate.py", line 301, in build_activate
        return self._build_activate_stack(env_name_or_prefix, False)
      File "/Users/username/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/conda/activate.py", line 323, in _build_activate_stack
        return self.build_reactivate()
      File "/Users/username/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/conda/activate.py", line 503, in build_reactivate
        new_path = self.pathsep_join(self._replace_prefix_in_path(conda_prefix, conda_prefix))
      File "/Users/username/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/conda/activate.py", line 628, in _replace_prefix_in_path
        if path_list[last_idx + 1] == library_bin_dir:
    IndexError: list index out of range

`$ /Users/username/opt/anaconda3/bin/conda shell.posix activate base`

  environment variables:
                 CIO_TEST=<not set>
        CONDA_DEFAULT_ENV=base
                CONDA_EXE=/Users/username/opt/anaconda3/bin/conda
             CONDA_PREFIX=/Users/username/opt/anaconda3
    CONDA_PROMPT_MODIFIER=(base)
         CONDA_PYTHON_EXE=/Users/username/opt/anaconda3/bin/python
               CONDA_ROOT=/Users/username/opt/anaconda3
              CONDA_SHLVL=1
                     PATH=/Users/username/opt/anaconda3/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/u
                          sr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin:/Users/username/opt/anaconda3/bin
       REQUESTS_CA_BUNDLE=<not set>
            SSL_CERT_FILE=<not set>

     active environment : base
    active env location : /Users/username/opt/anaconda3
            shell level : 1
       user config file : /Users/username/.condarc
 populated config files : /Users/username/.condarc
          conda version : 4.8.0
    conda-build version : 3.18.9
         python version : 3.7.4.final.0
       virtual packages : __osx=10.15.2
       base environment : /Users/
username/opt/anaconda3  (writable)
           channel URLs : https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/osx-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/osx-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
          package cache : /Users/username/opt/anaconda3/pkgs
                          /Users/username/.conda/pkgs
       envs directories : /Users/username/opt/anaconda3/envs
                          /Users/username/.conda/envs
               platform : osx-64
             user-agent : conda/4.8.0 requests/2.22.0 CPython/3.7.4 Darwin/19.2.0 OSX/10.15.2
                UID:GID : 501:20
             netrc file : None
           offline mode : False


An unexpected error has occurred. Conda has prepared the above report.

__conda_activate:13: command not found: 1
                                                                                
username git/master  
❯ /Users/username/.anaconda/navigator/a.tool ; exit;
/Users/username/.anaconda/navigator/a.tool: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token `('
/Users/username/.anaconda/navigator/a.tool: line 1: `bash --init-file <(echo "source activate /Users/username/opt/anaconda3/envs/datascience;")'

[プロセスが完了しました]
```

**環境**
os: macOS Catalina
シェル: zsh

**試したこと**

```
conda init zsh
conda update conda
conda update jupyter
```

一時　jupyter notebook　が使えなくなっていましたが、使えるようになりました。

Comment: 回答される方へ　https://teratail.com/questions/229952

Comment: [これ](https://qiita.com/zeppekipanda/items/33bc1be459992d05ba1c)では？

Answer (score 1):

コメントで教えていただいた記事を参考にしました。
記事に従い実行した後、zshに戻せばうまく行きました。

[MacにAnacondaをインストールし、Jupyter環境の構築 - Qiita](https://qiita.com/zeppekipanda/items/33bc1be459992d05ba1c)

```
# 起動シェルの変更
chsh -s /bin/bash
# 起動シェルを元に戻す
chsh -s /bin/zsh
```